# Protecting / Hiding the embedded JavaScript in a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, fpdf

**Short version**: is there a way to protect or hide the embedded JS from any user of the PDF, regardless of how they are opening it, and ideally without needing to use Adobe Pro (or a paid PDF tool) to do it?

**Background**:

I am creating a PDF containing embedded JavaScript. The JS code performs validations, creates annotations, calculates things, etc... The JS may contain proprietary or sensitive logic (particularly on the calculation side).

I don't have Adobe Pro or any of the (paid) PDF editing tools. As I understand things, one cannot view the embedded JS using Acrobat Reader but someone with Adobe Pro (or an actual PDF editor) could open a PDF and view all of the embedded JS.

I'm currently using FPDF (together with a host of extensions) to generate the PDFs, so if it is possible to hide the JS, first prize is being able to do it without actually having to purchase PDF editors to do it (partially because of expense, partially because the PDFs need to be generated programatically).

Also open to alternative suggestions as to how to hide / protect embedded JS in a PDF file. Obfuscating the JS code (for example, minimising it) makes it harder to extract the logic in the JS, but still not impossible.

Comment: Don't obfuscate javascript, it can always be reversed, do server side validation if there is any sensitive data involved

Comment: what happens to the document after the user has filled it in and the JS has run? Do they upload it back to a server somewhere for the data to be processed? If so, then re-validate the data on the server. Never trust anything which comes from the client. You can't necessarily even prove they used your original PDF, it could be a clone which appears to have the same fields etc, but missing all of the JS. Or they could manipulate the PDF as you mention. There's not really any totally foolproof way to do this just in the PDF AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks both - agreed. Data is validated upon extraction (couple of methods), as is the integrity and completeness of the PDF itself. Concern is less about the integrity of the data (that's solved) - its more about preventing any user from viewing the embedded JS to start with.